# How to invoke local RESTLET resource without full url?

Tags: java, restlet

I need to retrieve a list of given entities (apples) from another resource (fruitDelaer) I know I can do smt like this (somewhere in my fruitDealer resource implementation):

```
ClientResource applesResource = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8888/fruitShop/apples");

Representation response = applesResource.get();
```

But since this 'apples' resource is local to the one it's invoking it, **is there a way not to specify the full url**?

**NOTE**: I suspect this may have more to do with Java itself than restlet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542473/resteasy-invoke-service-inside-another-service

This might help.

Comment: Rather than going through a request cycle, why not access the resource's services directly?

Comment: @DaveNewton I was thinking that too but the get request populates some values (not shown in the question, but it could be for example how many results you want or similar) so if I access the resource class I'd have to populate those manually, kind of sucks :) Look at this example from the restlet doc, the seem to use the localhost url (Client-side consumption): http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/328-restlet/285-restlet.html

Comment: @JohnIdol That's just an example showing consuming a resource, doesn't say if it's in the same app. It sounds like your app is pretty tightly coupled; you should be able to use the underlying implementation without a lot of effort.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah I could do that but it would mean exposing those values that are usually populated via the restful request, which is somewhat weird. I guess the lesser evil wins though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restlet offers the RIAP pseudo-protocol (Restlet Internal Access Protocol), which lets you do exactly that, invoke resources local to your application|virtual host|component using an URI such as "riap://application/fruitShop/apples".

[Additional details here](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/48-restlet/86-restlet/45-restlet.html).

Comment: I am looking into this again and I am having difficulties getting this to work -- is there an example somewhere of using RIAP to consume a resource as a client?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider another approach. A `Service` that you could call from `fruitDealer` to retrieve what you need. There is a lot of work to be done creating objects and such that is not necessary.